# import userinputed string as a module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to import a file, which is inputed from user as a string

say:

```
a=raw_input("File : ")
import a #How do i import a user defined string which is actually a file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
m = __import__(a)
```

in this case `m` is object module, as example:

```
>>> m = __import__('sys')
>>> m.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages' ... ]
```

Answer (score 7):

Be very careful doing this. Importing arbitrary code is a terrible idea unless you are very sure that you know what you're doing.

That said, you can do this using the built-in `importlib` module:
http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html

```
importlib.import_module(a)
```

Comment: You should add the folder of the file to `sys.path` or it will fail.

Comment: Right, this is equivalent to `import a` in that it has to actually be able to find `a` in the module search locations, of which `sys.path` is the main one. Full docs with more detail than you'll usually need here: http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement